# Add rows in table only if those rows do not already exist in that same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of .csv files containing client information about their cloud usage. Each .csv contains data about one client and each file tracks what the client has used for the day.
I have one year worth of those files, for every client. For instance : I have client1__05022020, client1_06022020, client2_05022020, etc until client1_06022021 and that's so for all the other clients.

I have a temporary table named `Cloud__TMP`. In this table, I integrate 1 raw .csv file and then in a stored procedure, I have sql requests which fill other tables like my "client" table. Then I delete what's in `Cloud__TMP` and integrate another .csv and it goes on and on.

As I said, I have a "client" table with `id` (primary key), `idCloud` (`nvarchar`), `clientName` (`nvarchar`). I want to fill it with data from `Cloud__TMP`. Basically, there are 2 columns in `Cloud__TMP` that are of interest for my "client" table : Org (which corresponds to `idCloud`) and `OrgFullName` (which corresponds to `clientName`).
edit : It's important to note that there is a multitude of rows in each file since it's about cloud usage (everytime the client uses more or less, a new row is put in the .csv file). So, my columns `OrgFullName` and `idCloud` are filled the same client and the same cloud id many, many times.

My issue is that I have trouble making it so there are no duplicates in my "client" table. I tried a bunch of requests but I'm not very good at it and could use your help.

Here's one request I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO client (clientName, idCloud)
        SELECT OrgFullName, Org
        FROM Cloud__TMP AS Cloud
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM client WHERE Cloud.Org = client.idCloud)
```

Comment: Why do you want to find a slightly different way of doing it?  Does the code you've posted have some speciifc problem?

Comment: What is wrong with your insert ... It looks fine.

Comment: @CetinBasoz it wasn't working because my source table has duplicates (I edited my post and added screens)

Comment: @JeffUK My boss asked me to do it differently if I can find a way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insert is fine . . . unless the incoming data has duplicates.  You may want to remove those as well:

```
INSERT INTO client (clientName, idCloud)
    SELECT MAX(OrgFullName), Org
    FROM Cloud__TMP AS Cloud
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM client WHERE Cloud.Org = client.idCloud)
    GROUP BY Org;
```

This arbitrarily chooses one value when the incoming data has duplicates.

Comment: I've edited my post with screens and further explications on my source table which does have duplicates. Your request works perfectly so thank you very much :)